# Convert GQL query into JSON and Saving back to GAE Database

Tags: javascript, python, json, google-app-engine

I try to fetch datas from database and show datas in the webpage, and save the comments back to databse.

I use Python to building the sever and Google App Engine Database as my database because I didn't find any useful API which could provide useful dates for me.

For front end, I try to use JavaScript to implement webpage display and deal with database.

However, I don't not how to solve the problem of connection, which is:
    1, after fetch date, How to conver gql query into JSON, and send to frontend.
    2, After user typed, how to save back into google app engin database.

Thank you so much if anyone would like helping me.

the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <ul id="pagerender">
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

the sever code:

```
import webapp2, jinja2, os, re, json

from google.appengine.ext import db

class User(db.Model):

    username = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    pw_hash = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.StringProperty()

class Post(db.Model):

    img = db.LinkProperty(required = True)
    body = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required = True)

class Comment(db.Model):

    postid = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    cmt = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)



class MainPageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def render_template(self, template_name, **context):
    if not self.user:
        me = "Welcome Visit"
    else:
        me= self.user.username
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    response = t.render(me=me, **context)
    return response

 def get(self, username=""):

 """Fetch posts"""

    posts = Post.all().order('-created')
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(posts))
    response = self.render_template('mainpage.html', posts=posts, username=username)

def post(self,id):
    post = Post.get_by_id(int(id))
    if post:
        submitted_comment = self.request.get("commentname")
        # commentauthor = self.request.get("commentauthor")
        comment = Comment(
                postid = id,
                cmt= submitted_comment
                )
        comment.put()
        comments = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE postid = '%s'"% id)
        # t = jinja_env.get_template("post.html")
        response = self.render_template("post.html", post=post,comments=comments)
        self.response.out.write(response)   

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/.*', MainpageHandler)], debug=True)
```

the JS code:

```
function render(){
// window.location.reload();
$.ajax("/",{
    type:"GET",
    data:{
        fmt: 'json'
    },
    success: function(response){
        response.results.forEach(function(post)){
            var post_title = $("<h3 />").text(post.title);
            var post_img = $("<img/>").attr("src", post.img);
            var post_body = $("<P/>").text(post.body);
            var post_user = $("<p/>").attr("src", /sparkle/post.key().id()).text(post.author.username);
            var post_comment = $("<textarea/>").attr("id", commentconcept);
            var post_buttom = $("<button/>").attr("id", comment+post.key().id()).click(function(){
                postid = post.key().id());
                cmt = $("#commentconcept").val();
                comment = Comment(
                        postid = postid,
                        cmt= cmt
                        )
                comment.put()
            });

            var item_view = $("<li></li>").append(post_title),
                                          .append(post_img),
                                        .append(post_body),
                                        .append(post_user),
                                        .append(post_comment),
                                        append(post_buttom);
            $("#pagerender").append(item_view);
        }
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    render();
});
```